# how to store contents in C++ vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

so pretty much every problem on an Online judge requires the basic work of storing the a bunch of values and then processing them. I normally use std::vector for these, but i am concerned that using `push_back()` for storing each element is bad for performance.

Currently i do this :

```
vector<int> vec;
int x;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 cin>>x;
 vec.push_back(x);
}
```

but then i though if this would be better

```
vector<int> vec;
int x;
vec.reserve(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 cin>>vec[i];
```

Which is more suitable? , Is there any difference in performance?
And let's say i have a good reason to avoid C style arrays and yeah, i know the initial size of vector beforehand .

Comment: If you know the size ahead of time then yes, it is better to pre-allocate enough space to avoid re-allocations and copies.

Comment: well, the first version is more suitable, because the second version invokes undefined behavior (`reserve()` is not the same thing as `resize()`!!!). Also, if your loop contains user input, then why the heck are you even concerned about performance? It just doesn't matter. The user will take a gazillion times more time to hammer in their numbers than the difference between `push_back` and direct access.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It is for an online judge. , so the execution time affects the score.

Comment: @zapper but don't you understand that it doesn't matter? I/O manipulation is **way slower** than both `push_back` and the `[]` operator. If you are using `cin` and `cout`, they will dominate the execution time and you aren't gonna gain practically any performance from the vector, because the speed of I/O operations is already orders of magnitude lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, careful, in your second example there's a glaring mistake: `reserve` expands the *capacity* of the vector, i.e. the number of elements you can put in it without vector performing a reallocation, but does not affect its logical size. For this reason, if you do `reserve` you still have to do `push_back`, otherwise you are accessing logically-nonexistent elements in your loop. What you probably meant was `resize`, which expands both the logical size and the capacity to the requested size.

Now, coming to performance:

#### Plain `push_back` vs `reserve` + `push_back`: mostly the same (if copy is cheap)

Even without `reserve`, the vector will reach the needed capacity in amortized constant time (actually in O(log N) time, which is hidden anyway in the O(N) of the loop).

OK, if you already know for certain the size that your vector will take it will avoid reallocations, but don't jump through hoops to determine how much to reserve.

Exception: types with an expensive copy constructor (move constructor in C++11). If you are storing objects that are expensive to copy/move, you'll want to avoid reallocations, so `reserve` may help here (although usually you store such types by pointer, avoiding the problem).

#### `resize` + `operator[]`: faster for "simple" types

What I actually saw that boosts slightly the performance when dealing with simple types (typically PODs, or in general stuff with extremely simple constructor/assignment operator) is to do a `resize` beforehand, and then just do assignments through the `[]` operator.

This avoids the additional complexity of `push_back`, which has to check the capacity and increment the "logical size"; assignment through the subscript operator, OTOH, when optimized resolves to a handful of assembly instructions.

Of course you don't want to `resize` and assign when you have complex types, where the initial default construction and the assignment offset the light bookkeeping that `push_back` has to do.

Comment: What would be an example of a type that is expensive to move?

Comment: @FredOverflow: `struct S { S(S&& other) { std::system("wget https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-PostHistory.7z"); } };`

Answer (score 2):

Read documentation of [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). You'll notice that `reserve` is just for

> Request a change in capacity
>
> Requests that the vector capacity be at least enough to contain n elements.
>
> If n is greater than the current vector capacity, the function causes the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n (or greater).
>
> In all other cases, the function call does not cause a reallocation and the vector capacity is not affected.
>
> This function has no effect on the vector size and cannot alter its elements.

So you can't store elements after a `reserve`, you need to `resize`  first.

```
vec.resize(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 cin>>vec[i];
```

BTW, when you want to push some elements and you have an idea of how much elements, you should better `vec.reserve(10)`  before:

```
vec.reserve(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
 cin>>x;
 vec.push_back(x);
}
```

About performance issues: in your particular case you might not care (since I/O is much slower than `vector` functions). In general, you should try to `reserve` before a lot of `push_back`, since a `push_back` would internally do some `reserve` equivalent (re-allocation of some unknown implementation specific amount) if space is not enough. Perhaps not using `reserve` might trigger reallocation periodically, and you might want to avoid that.

I bet that storing in `vec[i]`  after a suitable `resize` is the fastest, since `operator []` is documented as:

> Returns a reference to the element at position n in the vector container.
>
> A similar member function, vector::at, has the same behavior as this operator function, except that vector::at is bound-checked and signals if the requested position is out of range by throwing an out_of_range exception.
>
> Portable programs should never call this function with an argument n that is out of range, since this causes undefined behavior.

BTW, most STL implementations (including `libstdc++` from [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) are somehow free software, so you could study their source code to understand what exactly is done, and you could always benchmark.

Comment: So is the `resize()` one is better or using `push_back()` after `reserve()` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd prefer option C:

```
const int num = 10;

std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(num);

std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), num, std::back_inserter(vec));
```

...but if you place a high value on the code being short, perhaps you'd prefer D:

```
std::vector<int> vec(num);

std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), num, vec.begin());
```

Personally, I don't like that quite as well (it's a bit less idiomatic, IMO) but it'll work perfectly well, and it is clearly shorter.

Answer (score 0):

`vector` automatically grows when it's `capacity` is not enough, so `push_back` is not a good idea if you knows the size prior.

Your second approach is better, but there is a problem: `reserve` and `resize` are not the same.

You have 2 ways to do it more efficiently:

1.

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.resize(10); // actually change the size, so your vec is now of size 10
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) // pre-increment is better
    cin >> vec[i];
```

2.

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10); // only enlarge the capacity, but size is still 0
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) // pre-increment is better
{
    cin >> x;
    vec.push_back(x); // would not trigger any memory reallocation, performance is fine
}
```

---

To be more detailed:

**`capacity` and `size`:**

`capacity` indicates the memory allocated for `vector`, so when this number is exceeded, the whole `vector` is copied to a new memory space, and this is not efficient, so try to avoid this as possible.

`size` is the number of current elements, it is `<=` capacity, whenever you do `push_back`, this number is increased by 1.

**`reserve` and `resize`:**

`reserve` changes the `capacity`, you tell the `vector` to "reserve" how many spaces for potential use, so if you can know your size, then call this function to make sure you can avoid memory reallocate. This function only change the `capacity`, but no touching `size`.

`resize` immediately change the `vector`'s `size`, it can also incur memory allocation. If your new `size` is larger than old `size`, the newly added element are default initialized.

Refer here for full information:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store more complex objects than just plain ints the fastest solution should be to create the objects in place (inside the vector) using emplace_back(), if your compiler supports that. Reserving enough space beforehand will prevent multiple reallocations.

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(const std::string& name, int x, int y);
};

std::vector<Widget> widgets;
widgets.reserve(nWidgets);
widgets.emplace_back("w1", 0, 0);
widgets.emplace_back("w2", 100, 20);
// ...
```